# Does RSpec allow me to select mocks with a matcher?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a number of calls to

```
Kernel.open(url).read
```

in some legacy code, which I'm trying to mock for characterisation tests before wide-scale refactoring.

I didn't like the way arguments are ignored by

```
allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to(receive_message_chain(:open, :read)
    .and_return(return_value))
```

so I replaced it with

```
def stub_kernel_open_read(args: '[arg1, arg2, k: v, etc]', returning:)
  allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to(receive(:open).with(*args)).and_return(double.tap { |d|
    allow(d).to(receive(:read)).and_return(returning)
  })
end
```

but I find I'm getting these sorts of errors:

```
       "http://my-fake-server/whatever" received :open with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("http://my-fake-server/whatever", {:http_basic_authentication=>["asdf", "asdf"]})
          got: ({:http_basic_authentication=>["asdf", "asdf"]})
   Diff:
   @@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
   -["http://my-fake-server/whatever",
   - {:http_basic_authentication=>["asdf", "asdf"]}]
   +[{:http_basic_authentication=>["asdf", "asdf"]}]

    Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

So I found that if I expanded my stub to this:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to(receive(:open).with(*args)) { |instance|
  return double.tap { |d|
    allow(d).to(receive(:read)) {
      return returning
    }
  }
}
```

then `instance` has the value of the URL. This is fine so far as it goes, and I could rig up a list of allowed URLs, but it feels mucky.

Is there something like

```
allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).that(eq('http://whatever')).to(receive(:open))
```

or am I just barking up entirely the wrong alley?

Obviously I could use global search-replace to wrap the `Kernel.open(url).read` code, and mock that global properly, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Does this legacy code use Kernel.open enough that you can't just change it to use Net::HTTP and then just use webmock? I mean you're really just replacing `Kernel.open(url).read` with `Net::HTTP.get(url)`.

Comment: Kernel.open.read handles 302 redirects; Net::HTTP doesn't, so it's not a drop-in replacement, sadly. Thanks for the suggestion though: I think I'll just go with the wrapper.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still an issue but Kernel.open has been regarded as a big security hole as its easy to mistakenly execute remote code.

Comment: @max Yeah, we should prohibit it, but our URLs are internal and we like the 302 redirects. I'll probably create an internal ticket for its replacement and a Rubocop hack to ban `require open-uri`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIU your question correctly, you need something like this, to tell the mock to behave "normally":

```
allow(Kernel).to receive(:open).with(url).and_return(stub)
allow(Kernel).to receive(:open).with(anything).and_call_original # I can't check now, but there's a chance this one should go first, but I doubt it
```

then just

```
allow(stub).to receive(:read).and_return('something')
```

If you have to mock `Kernel.open` for more URLs, it's getting a little bit messy but the principle is the same

```
allow(Kernel).to receive(:open).with(first_url).and_return(first_stub)
allow(Kernel).to receive(:open).with(second_url).and_return(second_stub)
allow(Kernel).to receive(:open).with(anything).and_call_original # I can't check now, but there's a chance this one should go first


allow(first_stub).to receive(:read).and_return('something')
allow(second_stub).to receive(:read).and_return('something else')
```

Unless I completely missed the point of your question?

Comment: I completely missed the difference between `allow(Kernel)` vs `allow_any_instance_of(Kernel)` - If I use `allow(Kernel)` then I get the url where I expected it. I really hate the Ruby type system. I've never found a compelling situation where wild duck typing is a meaningful part of a solution.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But if you can't change the code, the only thing I can suggest is to learn more. One thing that helped me was "Metaprogramming Ruby" https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Fixing the 'allow_any_instance_of' issue got me over the hump, so I have what I need for now. Longer term, we're moving to JRuby and rewriting the active code into Kotlin, which provides most of the purported advantages while being regular enough for the IDE to give active help. We only used Ruby originally because it came along with Calabash/Cucumber and nobody recognised the unreliable and unmaintainable code it would cause.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in RSpec's mocking system to cope with the fact that the 'Kernel.open(url)' method mock has the url as the instance if you use `allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to(receive(:open))`. so I cooked up a bodge, and then realised I didn't need the 'any_instance_of' bit:

```
def stub_kernel_open_read(url: 'fake://your_url_parameter_is_wrong', args: ['arg1', 'arg2', k: :v_etc], **rest)
  allow(Kernel).to(receive(:open).with(*([url] + args)).and_return(reading_double(rest)))
end

def reading_double(return_or_raise)
  double.tap do |d|
    if return_or_raise[:returning]
      allow(d).to(receive(:read).and_return(return_or_raise[:returning]))
    else
      allow(d).to(receive(:read).and_raise(return_or_raise[:raising]))
    end
  end
end
```

This code arose from trying to remove the use of `receive_message_chain` which was using 'any_instance'.

Oh, and I ran into all sorts of bizarre shenannigans trying to stub any methods with `(*a, **b)` arguments, even though that seems to work for the toy examples I tried to cook, so I have no idea what's going on. It's that sort of arcane nonsense that sets me against Ruby and duck-typing.